# Handling custom media queries in Sass with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have a Sass mixin for my media queries based on Twitter Bootstrap's responsive media queries:

```
@mixin respond-to($media) {
    @if $media == handhelds {
        /* Landscape phones and down */
        @media (max-width: 480px) { @content; }
    }
    @else if $media == small {
        /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
        @media (max-width: 767px) {@content; }
    }
    @else if $media == medium {
        /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { @content; }
    }
    @else if $media == large {
        /* Large desktop */
        @media (min-width: 1200px) { @content; }
    }
    @else {
        @media only screen and (max-width: #{$media}px) { @content; }
    }
}
```

And I call them throughout my SCSS file like so:

```
.link {
   color:blue;
   @include respond-to(medium) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I want to style multiple queries with the same styles. Right now I'm doing them like this:

```
.link {
    color:blue; /* this is fine for handheld and small sizes*/

    /*now I want to change the styles that are cascading to medium and large*/
    @include respond-to(medium) {
        color: red;
    }
    @include respond-to(large) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

but I'm repeating code so I'm wondering if there is a more concise way to write it so I can target multiple queries. Something like this so I don't need to repeat my code (I know this doesn't work):

```
@include respond-to(medium, large) {
    color: red;
}
```

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

Comment: Well, it's still cascading style, so what's fit for medium fits also for large (as you're using min-width Media queries) no?

Comment: No so I should've been more specific (I'll edit the question). Let's say my default styles (which are fine for handheld and mobile) would be color:blue; but then I want medium and large to be color:red;. It does cascade but I want to overwrite medium and large. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

A mixin like that leaves you in a position that's not very flexible, and not just because you're using px (see: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/).  Simply put, you've made your mixin too specific and not very reusable for other sites.

I'm currently using a collection of 4 mixins to handle the most common media queries:  min-width, max-width, between, and outside (I've sampled min-width and between below)

```
$output-media-width: true !default; // true = all, otherwise use a list of numeric values (eg. 320px 23em)

@mixin media-min-width($bp) {
    @if type-of($output-media-width) != list {
        @media (min-width: $bp) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        $output-bp: find-comparable($bp, $output-media-width);
        @if not comparable($output-bp, $bp) {
            @debug "Output breakpoint: #{$output-bp}, Chosen minimum width: #{$bp}";
        } @else if $output-bp >= $bp {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@mixin media-between($bp1, $bp2) {
    @if type-of($output-media-width) != list {
        @media (min-width: $bp1) and (max-width: make-less-than($bp2)) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        $output-bp1: find-comparable($bp1, $output-media-width);
        $output-bp2: find-comparable($bp2, $output-media-width);
        @if not comparable($output-bp1, $bp1) or not comparable($output-bp2, $bp2) {
            @debug "Output breakpoints: #{$output-bp1} and #{$output-bp2}, Chosen breakpoints: #{$bp1} and #{$bp2}";
        } @else if $output-bp2  >= $bp1 and $output-bp2 < $bp2 {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@function find-comparable($val, $list) {
    @each $item in $list {
        @if comparable($val, $item) {
            @return $item;
        }
    }
}

@function make-less-than($val) {
    @return if(unit($val) == em, $val - .001, $val - 1);
}
```

This mixin suite lets me generate a responsive CSS file or a collection of non-responsive CSS files at any width I desire (specifically for devices that don't take kindly to media queries) just by having a variable like this at the top of my file:

```
$output-media-width: 800px 60em;
```

A list of sizes lets me use px in those rare cases where em is inappropriate (such as for dealing with images).

```
// Device widths
$device-x-narrow: 23em; // 320px
$device-narrow: 35em; // 480px
$device-medium: 60em; // 800px
$device-wide: 70em; // 1000px

article.event {
    @mixin tableify {
//      footer { display: table-row }
        footer section { display: table-cell }
        footer section + section { padding-left: 2em }
    }

    @include media-min-width($device-medium) { // 2-col layout still
        #main > & { // single event view
            @include tableify;
        }
    }

    // sometimes you need a non-standard breakpoint, too...
    @include media-min-width(27em) { // narrow devices
        section & {
            @include tableify;
        }
    }

    @include media-max-width(27em) {
        footer section.categories ul {
            display: block;
            padding-left: 0;
            li { display: inline }
            li + li { margin-left: 1em }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using those px-based media queries because I'm using Twitter Bootstrap so they're based on that. Not sure if I entirely follow what is going on in your code, but it looks impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that @cimmanon answered my question before I posted that I was using Twitter Bootstrap, it had some really interesting ideas in it which I think I'll apply from now on for my Sass projects that use Twitter Bootstrap. Here is what I found worked great:

```
/* Responsive dimensions */
$handheld-max: 479px;
$small-min: $handheld-max + 1;
$small-max: 767px;
$medium-min: $small-max + 1;
$medium-max: 979px;
$large-min: $medium-max + 1;
$large-max: 1199px;
$xlarge: 1200;

/*Responsive query mixins */
@mixin media-above($min) {
  @media (min-width: $min) { @content; }
}
@mixin media-below($max) {
  @media (max-width: $max) { @content; }
}
@mixin media-between($min, $max) {
  @media (min-width: $min) and (max-width: $max) { @content; }
}
```

and then call it in my code like so (based on my request in the question):

```
.link {
    color: blue;
    @mixin media-above($medium-min){
       color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap-sass variables, I defined such mixins in SASS syntax:

```
=media-width-below($max)
  @media (max-width: $max)
    @content

=media-width-between($min, $max)
  @media (min-width: $min), (max-width: $max)
    @content

=media-width-above($min)
  @media (min-width: $min)
    @content

=media-xs
  +media-width-above($screen-xs-min)
    @content

=media-sm
  +media-width-above($screen-sm-min)
    @content

=media-md
  +media-width-above($screen-md-min)
    @content

=media-lg
  +media-width-above($screen-lg-min)
    @content
```

Those mixins will be useable just like `+make-sm-column` or `.col-md-5` classes. You can just use it like this:

```
body
  +media-xs
    background-color: yellow
  +media-sm
    background-color: blue
  +media-md
    background-color: red
  +media-lg
    background-color: green
```

When you will be making your browser smaller by changing it from large to xs, you'll see colors in this order: green, red, blue, yellow.